# Material design 3 top-app bar is hiding when scroll up?

Tags: android, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, material-components-android, material-components

I am using the **Material design 3** android plugin **top-app bar is hiding when scrolling up**?
**Ref this screenshot**, it is working in material design, not md3.
Plz help me, with how to fix

**here is my full code :** https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13zTdk0c32F_q3MHfo5w-iOvUy8BF9isV?usp=sharing

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.Material3">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/image3"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/love_music"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/app_name"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/app_name"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>


            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar

                app:menu="@menu/menu_scrolling"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
                app:liftOnScroll="false"

                android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.PopupOverlay"
               />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```